# How to redeploy google cloud platform using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I'm trying to find a quick command to redeploy a pod in Kubernetes.

1. Currently, I pushed my docker image to google cloud.
2. Then I list my pods

```
kubectl -n pringadi get pods
        NAME                                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
        audit-server-757ffd5dd-ztn5s                                 1/1     Running     0          38m
        configs-service-75c98f68c7-q928q                            1/1     Running     0          36m
```

3. I edit the deployment config
   `kubectl edit deployment audit-server`.
4. Update/change the image name.
5. Save and exit.

Kubernetes immediately recognizes the change and redeploy `audit-server`.

**Question:**
What if I pushed my docker image (a newer image) to google cloud with the same name (Step 4) and just want to redeploy the `audit-server` based on the current image. Is there a command for that? It a tedious job to keep editing the deployment config (Step 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wholly unclear what you're trying to do, but taking a guess:

`kubectl set image deploy audit-server "*=us.gcr.io/whatever/whateverelse:12345"` will bump the image in your deployment without having to invoke your editor

Alternatively, use something like [skaffold](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold#readme) or its competitors to continuously push and reload a Pod for development

Comment: That command rewrite all image names in audit-server to the new value. Is it possible to make that command to be more specific?

Comment: Sure, yes; you just didn't specify anything about your deployment so there is no way anyone could have **guessed** your setup. The `*` in that should be replaced by the name of the container (for example: `my-app=us.gcr.io/whatever/whatever` to use rabello's example descriptor)

Comment: Thanks! I think the keyword is patch. Like the -p in this command `kubectl patch deployment audit-server -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"audit-server","image": "gcr.io/MY_PROJECT/audit-server:pringadi-snapshot", "imagePullPolicy": "Always"}]}}}}'`

Comment: If you prefer the longer command, yes, I believe they are both probably implemented behind the scenes by `kubectl` using that same mechanism

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a deployment with the `imagePullPolicy: Always` and kill your pod after make a change. it will force your deployment download the image again.

From [Kubernetes Docs:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images)

> `imagePullPolicy: Always`: the image is pulled every time the pod is started.

Example:

```yaml
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: Always
EOF
```

Then after pulled your image, delete the running pod, deployment will download the image again:

```
kubectl delete pods -l app=my-app
```

Check the new container:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=my-app
```

I hope that helps.